# Continuous inverse functions.

Tags: general-topology

I am asking this question because I am having somewhat of a difficult time finding a direct answer searching online.

I know that a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if given an open set $O$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $X$.

Let's say I have an open set in $X$, call it $R$, and I also know $f$ is continuous, does showing $f(R)$ open in $Y$ give any information regarding the continuity of $f^{-1}$?

Now, I want to conclude $f^{-1}$ is continuous but my difficulties of finding a straightforward answer leads me to believe this is not a valid conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not bijective, then $f^{-1}$ does not exist. So, $f$ may be open, but we can not say that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: Say $f$ is bijective, for example it is strictly increasing/decreasing would my conclusion then be valid?

Comment: Then, yes, $f$ open implies that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.  This is because $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$.

Comment: Thank you! It seemed correct but I could not find a straightforward answer.